# How do I root my Azpen A727 tablet?

Tags: rooting

How do I root my Azpen A727 tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned how to do this from [here](https://annoyingtechnicaldetails.wordpress.com/2014/07/31/rooting-a-20-tablet-azpen-a727/)

I did this from a Linux PC with ADB installed.  It may be possible from a Windows PC with ADB installed but I could never get the tablet to connect as an installer over USB on Windows.

> Turns out it was dead simple, really, it came rooted. Here’s how I
>   installed Superuser on it so I can use apps that use root.
>
> 1. Download [superuser.zip](http://download.clockworkmod.com/superuser/superuser.zip)
> 2. Unzip `superuser.zip`
> 3. `adb root` (to run adb as root user on the tablet)
> 4. `adb remount`
> 5. `adb push Superuser.apk /system/app/`
> 6. `adb push armeabi/su /system/xbin/su`
> 7. `adb shell chmod 6755 /system/xbin/su`
> 8. `adb shell ln -s /system/xbin/su /system/bin/su`
> 9. `wget https://github.com/koush/Superuser/raw/master/init.superuser.rc`
> 10. `adb push init.superuser.rc /`

Comment: This worked for me, host is an Ubuntu 16.04 installation. I had to do everything as root though, ADB would not see the A727 as a user.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished rooting my Azpen A727. It was super easy.

I used 'Kingo Android ROOT' (https://www.kingoapp.com/android-root.htm) for Windows; It was literally as easy as one click and took all of 60 seconds.

Comment: Cool! I could never get mine to connect to a Windows PC.